# Which program can I use to draw schematics?

Tags: schematics

I would like to draw this schematic for my report.
It will be used just for drawing and not for technical things.

An example is this I found online.

[image]

Which kind of program do you use?

Answer (score 3):

[CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) for example.
Digikey's [SchemeIt](http://www.digikey.com/schemeit) is another one.
They are online, so you don't need to install anything.
Another one could be [Kicad](http://www.kicad-pcb.org/display/KICAD/KiCad+EDA+Software+Suite), it's free (opensource), but you have to download it and install on your pc.